# How to quick install mercurial server on windows

Tags: mercurial

A simple way to quickly install and use mercurial on windows allowing push.

Answer (score 2):

Iam not sure if this wasnt your way already, but TortoiseHg is nice gui for mercurial, and instalation comes with mercurial packed in, since install is .msi it is very simple.

See more here: http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/

Comment: The question is about "server". Do you use TortoiseHg on a server too?